# Imagemagick scale and image quality

Tags: image, resize, imagemagick, scale

I'm scaling an image down to 50% of its ratio with the convert command and -scale parameter. The generated image quality is pretty bad. Is there any extra option i can use to get a better result ?

Answer (score 10):

Using `-sharpen 0x1.2` with `-resize x%` with `-quality 95` produces good results for me.

Comment: You need to specify the order of the arguments ... for ImageMagick is important

Answer (score 8):

`-scale` is quick but I belive `-resize` or `-thumbnail` is better and you can use any filters you like.

Comment: quality goes this way up:
--thumbnail, --scale, --resize

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to create thumbnails of PDFs and was getting poor results until I added `-density 400`, which is a suggestion I found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=12235#p40279). Below is an example of the difference it can make. I got the PDF from [here](http://ankn.uaf.edu/publications/clipart/). Look at the bear and also the lines behind the bird.

## Without `-density 400`

Full command: `convert -resize 500x500 catalog.pdf[0] catalog-page1-resized.png`

File size: 180 KB

[image: Image without -density 400]

## With `-density 400`

Full command: `convert -density 400 -resize 500x500 catalog.pdf[0] catalog-page1-resized.png`

File size: 185 KB

[image: Image with -density 400]

Answer (score 1):

Using `-quality 80 -adaptive-resize` is better for larger photos.

If you need to blur the output, use `-interpolative-resize` instead of `-adaptive-resize`